# What is returned if find_link can't find the link?

Tags: perl, www-mechanize

In perl,
I use WWW::Mechanize->find_link(text=>'my_text'); My question is what is returned if the link is not found.

My purpose is to check whether a link exist then Mechanize::follow_link();;

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It returns an undefined link. At that point, you need to decide what to do...

```
my $link = WWW::Mechanize->find_link(text=>'my_text');
if ( not defined $link ) {
    say "Here be dragons...";
}
```

You could probably do this in one step:

```
if ( my $link = WWW::Mechanize->find_link(text=>'my_text') ) {
    Do something with "$link";
}
```

The problem is that `$link` will disappear outside of the `if` statement (if you're using `use strict;` which, of course you are).

Answer (score 1):

The docs are pretty clear about it:

> If it fails to find a link it returns undef.

http://metacpan.org/pod/WWW::Mechanize

Answer (score 1):

[Let's see what the docs say!](http://search.cpan.org/~ether/WWW-Mechanize-1.73/lib/WWW/Mechanize.pm#%24mech-%3efind_link%28_..._%29)

> Finds a link in the currently fetched page. It returns a WWW::Mechanize::Link object which describes the link. (You'll probably be most interested in the url() property.) **If it fails to find a link it returns undef.**